# Django static file in if statement

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, django-1.11

I am trying to display either or (`<img>` or `<h1>`) if an image is retrieved from a static URL.

So if this fails to load an image.

```
{%for team in object_list|slice:":1"%}
<img src="{% static "/img/Teams/" %}{{team.teamname}}.png" class="mx-auto mb-1" alt="{{team.teamname}}">
{%endfor%}
```

I would like to display a `<h1>` and have none of the code above loaded.

```
{%for team in object_list|slice:":1"%}
<h1>{{team.teamname}}</h1>
{%endfor%}
```

Im really unsure about the best way to go about resolving this condition. Is it possible to use a

```
{% if {% static "/img/Teams/" %}{{team.teamname}}.png" %}
```

or some type of javascript?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Did you add the `{% load static %}` line on top of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone looking for a possible solution for this problem. This is what i ended up using. A little Jquery to do the job

```
<script>  
    $("img").on("error", function() {
      var h = document.createElement("H1");
      var t = document.createTextNode(this.alt);
      h.appendChild(t);
      this.replaceWith(h); 
    });
</script>
```